# Is there a comprehensive list of NASA contractors with a list of projects that they are assigned to do?

Tags: nasa, space-industry

Knowing that contracts come and go over time, where can I find a list of current companies who have contracts with NASA to either do research or build stuff for them?  My goal is to get an overall feel for who is doing what in the space industry, and I think that looking to the contracts that NASA gives out is a good way to find one piece of the puzzle.  I'm not only looking for a list of specific contractors, but also a description of what each contractor is doing for NASA.

I'm hoping that, if such a list exists, that it is a dynamic list that gets updated over time as contracts are completed, rebidded, and won.  Any help obtaining such information  would be greatly appreciated.

If such information is limited to NASA personnel, who can I contact at NASA for such information?

Comment: I would challenge your assertion that NASA contracts alone will give you a good picture of the entire space industry. Defense sector government business is perhaps on par with NASA spending, and the commercial (e.g. telecom) market, while smaller than the above, is not negligible. I don't have sources to offer (which is why I didn't write an answer) but you should keep this in mind.

Comment: Concur. The DOD spends much more on space than NASA does.

Comment: DOD contracts should be publicly available except for classified projects, on the same website listed in Mark Omo's answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can see all the external spending by Agency for the government at [usaspending.gov](https://www.usaspending.gov), Just do an advanced search limiting the awarding agency to NASA.

Edit: Search links go stale after a while, [here](https://archive.org/details/all_contracts_prime_transactions_1) is an archive of all Awards made by NASA in FY2018.